# Split Cell's Vertical Text Into Multiple Columns

Tags: excel

I have an excel cell that contains an address. I want the address to be split into separate cells:

Address
City 
State 
Zip

What's unique is these items are stacked vertically, otherwise I would simply use Data > Text to Columns:

[image]

Update: I have tried the delimiter option, however I am not able to split all lines:

[image]

Comment: If you are using a newer version of excel which has flash fill, U can do it using that feature.

Start typing just the name in the next column, after 2 cells, excel should prompt you with auto-filling the rest of the column. You'll have to repeat that for each column.

Comment: Thanks, was definitely looking for a more automated solution

Comment: It's only "displaying" vertically (because you have the Wrap Text button enabled for that cell).  If you turn of wrapping, you'll see that it's actually just one long line. (with occasional Linefeed characters.)

Comment: @ashleedawg It's apparently *not*! Look at the length of the "wrapped" lines - they are **much** shorter than the available room in the cell. I strongly believe that *all* the "wrapping" is done by Linefeed character only.

Comment: The Excel file was exported from QB online

Comment: Please put there the REAL input and the REAL output. John Smith could not get swapped like that in a natural way.

Answer (score 2):

Your are *soooo* close to the solution :) Yes, `Data` -> `Text to columns` is it.

The trick is that you use as delimiter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, this will type the `new-line` character.

Credit: https://trumpexcel.com/split-multiple-lines/

BTW, the Google search string for this was `excel split cells with multiple lines`.

Comment: I have tried the solution, but it is not quite working as expected, please see updated question

Comment: How did John and Smith get switched around?

Answer (score 0):

The following will convert a long list in a column. If you only have a single cell of contact information, you're better off doing it manually.

```
Option Explicit

Sub gatherAddress()
    Dim i As Long, var As Variant, tmp As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        'put the new header labels in the top row
        .Cells(1, "B").Resize(1, 4) = Array("Address", "City", "State", "Zip")

        'collect the values from column A
        var = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2

        'make room for processed values
        ReDim Preserve var(LBound(var, 1) To UBound(var, 1), _
                           LBound(var, 2) To UBound(var, 2) + 4)

        'process the address into separate cells
        For i = LBound(var, 1) To UBound(var, 1)
            'split the billing address on the linefeed
            tmp = Split(var(i, 1), vbLf)

            'strip address line
            var(i, 2) = tmp(1)
            'strip city
            var(i, 3) = Split(tmp(2), Chr(44))(0)
            'strip city and zip
            var(i, 4) = Split(tmp(2), Chr(44))(1)
            'strip zip/zip+4 code
            var(i, 5) = Split(var(i, 4), Chr(32))(UBound(Split(var(i, 4), Chr(32))))
            'remove zip from city
            var(i, 4) = Trim(Replace(var(i, 4), var(i, 5), vbNullString))
        Next i

        'put the processed values back into the worksheet
        .Cells(2, "A").Resize(UBound(var, 1), UBound(var, 2)) = var
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate the help, but unfamiliar with excel programming. Where would I run this code?